# Copying shared_ptr<Interface> for classes that act like values

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, shared-ptr

Here is my problem. I have an interface and two derived classes:

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
class Derived1 : public Interface;
class Derived2 : public Interface;
```

Then, I also have a Value class containing a shared_ptr whose purpose is point to one of the two derived classes:

```
class Value
{
public:
     Value();
     Value(const Value&);
private:
     shared_ptr<Interface> p_;
};
```

As I want my Value class to act like a value, I want my copy constructor to make a copy of the pointed Derived object. However, I can't write

```
Value::Value(const Value& value) : 
    p_(make_shared<Interface>(*value.p_))
{ }
```

as Interface contains a purely virtual function. `*value.p_` must be a Derived type. I don't know how to manage this problem properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you'd like something like http://wg21.link/p0201 (a [reference implementation](https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value) is available)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to manage this problem properly.

Why not use a virtual clone() method?

```
class Interface
{
public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
  virtual std::shared_ptr<Interface> clone()=0;
};

class Derived1 : public Interface {
    void f() {};
  std::shared_ptr<Interface> clone()
  {
    return std::make_shared<Derived1>(*this);
  }
};
```

Then in your copy constructor, you can use something like the following to copy the pointer:

```
Value::Value(const Value& value)
{
    this->p_ = value.p_->clone();
}
```

Take a look at this as an example: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/copy-of-abc-via-clone.html

Comment: Why does `Value::p_` need to be a public member? This is not the case in the link you gave.

Comment: It needs to be because you are accessing it in the copy constructor.

It seems to be pretty similar to me. I also gave you an example on how that can be used in your case.

Comment: UPDATE: My bad but you don't have to declare a variable public for it to be used in the copy constructor. You would have to only if you were to use it inside your custom clone() method.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is exactly what the proposed `polymorphic_value` is intended to solve (it imparts value semantics on a polymorphic object).

`polymorphic_value<T>` can own and perform deep copies of an object derived from `T`.

The ISO C++ proposal is here http://wg21.link/p0201

A reference implementation is here https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value

I am the author of both the paper and reference implementation.

I have found polymorphic_value to be useful in removing large quantities of hard-to-write boilerplate code. I'd be interested to know if it solves your problem too.

Comment: `polymorphic_value` is exactly answering to my problem. I just didn't have time to use the implementation you and @KerrekSB gave me. It would be really nice if `polymorphic_value` would be part of the ISO C++.